# How do i call this method for debugging?

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I'm trying to call a method from this class. Calling for check_config() method to print the value of c.
New to python and some debugging advice would be great.

Tried BirdChecker.config_check() but getting error:
TypeError: unbound method check_config() must be called with BirdChecker instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I expect to print the value of c from the method config_check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `check_config` is an instance method, which means it needs to be called on an instance of your class `BirdChecker`. Try:

```
bird_checker = BirdChecker(control_socket=BIRD_CONTROL_SOCKET, ignore=True)
bird_checker.config_check()
```

The TLDR on instance vs. static methods is that instance methods must be called on an instance of a class, whereas a static method can be called on a class itself. The rule of thumb is to use instance methods only when you need access to data specific to an instance of the class. Since you need access to the `control_socket` for `_send_query` it makes sense that it's an instance method! However, if `BIRD_CONTROL_SOCKET` and/or `ignore` will never be different from instance to instance, you may want to reconsider.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the code, all the other methods are working except for check_config(). Could you please take a look at _config_check() and check_config(). It sort of runs into a loop

Comment: I can no longer see the original source code, did you remove it?

Comment: The current code snippet is substantially different from the original one, so you may want to ask a new question. That being said, `exit` will exit out before anything is printed. You may want to move that command down.